# How to unwrap_or to String

Tags: types, rust, unwrap

When using `unwrap_or`, how do I get a `String`?

I've distilled my problem down to this (with more type annotation than needed):

```
fn main() {
    let mut blah: String;
    let opt: Option<&str> = Some("foo");
    blah = opt.unwrap_or("bar");
}
```

This (reasonably) tells me that we need a `String` not a `&str`.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:33:12
   |
33 |     blah = opt.unwrap_or("bar");
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found &str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
   = note:    found type `&str`
```

So I try to provide the type wanted.

```
blah = opt.unwrap_or("bar".to_string());
```

But I get told off:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:33:26
   |
33 |     blah = opt.unwrap_or("bar".to_string());
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &str, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected type `&str`
   = note:    found type `std::string::String`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:33:12
   |
33 |     blah = opt.unwrap_or("bar".to_string());
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found &str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
   = note:    found type `&str`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misread the first error. The problem is not in the type passed to `unwrap_or()`, but in the type *returned* by `unwrap_or()`. Since you are assigning to a `String`, the right-hand-side of the assignment must also provide a `String`. The original error can be fixed simply by adding `to_string()` after the `unwrap_or`:

```
let mut blah: String;
let opt: Option<&str> = Some("foo");
blah = opt.unwrap_or("bar").to_string();
```

It is of course also possible for `Option` to contain a string, in which case your attempted fix would work just fine:

```
let mut blah: String;
let opt: Option<String> = Some("foo".to_string());
blah = opt.unwrap_or("bar".to_string());
```

Note that the type annotations are not required in either variable, Rust's type inference is smart enough to figure it out on its own.

Comment: Thanks! The second option is what I needed.

Comment: @MartinAlgesten Yup, I figured it out after taking another look at the question. It's now presented as the first option. :)